# Why isn't this script running from the masterpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a Page that is associated with a master page.  In the master page, I put the css links in the head section and I put the jquery script tag and the script that contains the function to toggle the grid, but when it is not working.  Looks like it is not even calling showhide when I click on an item.

Here is a snippet of the master page:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="MainLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="ajaxtab.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="pager.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="subgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      //master: id of div element that contains the information about master data
      //details: id of div element wrapping the details grid
      function showhide(master, detail) {
          //First child of master div is the image
          var src = $(master).children()[0].src;
          //Switch image from (+) to (-) or vice versa.
          if (src.endsWith("plus.png"))
              src = src.replace('plus.png', 'minus.png');
          else
              src = src.replace('minus.png', 'plus.png');

          //Set new image
          $(master).children()[0].src = src;

          //Toggle expand/collapse                   
          $(detail).slideToggle("normal");
      }
</script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Here is the div that contains the showhide function in the onclick event in the aspx page:

```
<div class="searchgroup" 
id='<%#String.Format("master{0}",Container.DataItemIndex)%>'
onclick='showhide(<%#String.Format("\"#master{0}\"",Container.DataItemIndex)%>
,
<%#String.Format("\"#detail{0}\"",Container.DataItemIndex) %>)'>
<asp:Image ID="imgCollapsible" 
           CssClass="first" 
           ImageUrl="plus.png" 
           Style="margin-right: 5px;"
           runat="server" />

<span class="searchheader"><%#Eval("Business")%></span>
</div>
```

Here is html it generates for the master and detail div:

```
//master div
<div class="searchgroup"   
     id='master0'                                                     
     onclick='showhide("#master0","#detail0")'>

<img id="ctl00_ContentPanel_gvMaster_ctl02_imgCollapsible" 
     class="first" src="plus.png" 
     style="border-width:0px;margin-right: 5px;" />
     <span class="searchheader">ABC</span>
</div>

//details div
<div id='detail0' class="searchdetail">
<div>
<table class="searchgrid"
       id="ctl00_ContentPanel_gvMaster_ctl02_gvDtails">
<tr>
<th>Status</th>
<tr class="searchrow">
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

I could not get the JQuery working and I was running out of time, so for now I decided to use the collapsible panel externder from the ajax control toolkit.  When I get time, I will investigate the JQuery Issue, Thanks for all your suggestions so far.  If anyone has any more, please let me know.

Comment: @Xaisoft try to debug it a bit, review the html source generated and make sure it gets into showhide. There are things that are just faster to identify when working with the actual code.

Comment: My thoughts exactly -- view the rendered html and if you're still stuck edit your post to include the relevant parts of the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is throwing an error at src.endsWith("plus.png") because there is no built in endsWith function in js.  replace that with src.substr(-8) == "plus.png" instead and it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      //master: id of div element that contains the information about master data
      //details: id of div element wrapping the details grid
      function showhide(master, detail) {
          //First child of master div is the image
          var src = $(master).children()[0].src;
          //Switch image from (+) to (-) or vice versa.
          if (src.substr(-8) == "plus.png")
              src = src.replace('plus.png', 'minus.png');
          else
              src = src.replace('minus.png', 'plus.png');

          //Set new image
          $(master).children()[0].src = src;

          //Toggle expand/collapse                   
          $(detail).slideToggle("normal");
      }
</script>
```

EDIT - Working example:

**MasterPage.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          //master: id of div element that contains the information about master data
          //details: id of div element wrapping the details grid
          function showhide(master, detail) {
              //First child of master div is the image
              var src = $(master).children()[0].src;
              //Switch image from (+) to (-) or vice versa.
              if (src.substr(-8) == "plus.png")
                  src = src.replace('plus.png', 'minus.png');
              else
                  src = src.replace('minus.png', 'plus.png');

              //Set new image
              $(master).children()[0].src = src;

              //Toggle expand/collapse                   
              $(detail).slideToggle("normal");
          }
    </script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default2.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div class="searchgroup" id='master0' onclick='showhide("#master0","#detail0")'>

    <img id="ctl00_ContentPanel_gvMaster_ctl02_imgCollapsible" class="first" src="plus.png" style="border-width:0px;margin-right: 5px;" />
     <span class="searchheader">ABC</span>
    </div>

    <div id='detail0' class="searchdetail">
        <div>
            <table class="searchgrid"
               id="ctl00_ContentPanel_gvMaster_ctl02_gvDtails">
                <tr>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="searchrow">
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: How come I don't get this error when I don't use a master page.  As soon as I put the script in the head section of the master page, showhide function does not fire and when I set breakpoints in firebug, it says undefined for everything

Comment: Is it also possible the JQuery has an endsWidth function.

Comment: @xaisoft, not sure why you didnt get it.  throws it in ff3 for me "src.endsWith is not a function" Line: 17

Comment: I'm using firefox also, but like I said, it is working when I test it on a page that does not have a masterpage associated with it, but when I put it on a page with the masterpage, it does not work.  Am I putting the scripts in the correct location in the masterpage?

Comment: @xaisoft, not sure why its not working for you.  see if the example i added works.  other than a missing </tr> i dont see any reason it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

" Looks like it is not even calling showhide when I click on an item." If you simplify the function with just an alert() function, does it work.

The code looks fine to me. Maybe there is some id mismatch.

Comment: If I put alert("hello"); in the showhide(master,detail) function, it works fine.

Comment: Then your originals statement " Looks like it is not even calling showhide when I click on an item." is not correct.

Jquery select statement may not select the right object. Check the return value of select object before proceed.

Comment: How can I debug the javascript, I can't put a break point. I am working in VS 2008

Comment: Hope this will help.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/19/vs-2008-javascript-debugging.aspx

This is from famous "ScottGu" bible :-)

Comment: Debugging javascript in Visual Studio is a pain in my opinion.  You can debug javascript easily if you have firefox with the firebug extension.  Its definitely the way to go for javascript debugging unless your encountering an IE only bug...

Answer (score 0):

You may check if jquery's path is correct in your page (that which uses this master page).

To be sure if its calling showhide() you can use Firebug in Firefox with a breakpoint in the function.

Also, it will give you more clues to debug and guess what is going wrong.

The code seems to be ok to me, too.

Comment: The code works when I tested on a page without a master page, but not if I put it in the master page.  The path is correct.  Can I place the script directly in the page itself, instead of the master.

Answer (score 0):

just a thought, if you right click view source on the browser, do you see the jquery path correctly? my experience tells me you need to resolve javascript urls on master pages (it works fine for css, but not js files)

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```